# Can I view the list of songs within a podcast while playing it?

Tags: iphone, ios, podcasts

When playing a podcast on my iPhone, can I view the names of the songs (or whatever show notes are embedded into the podcast metadata?

Answer (score 2):

There is a (non-obvious) way to see whatever information was provided by the person who made the podcast. *Whether it lists the songs will depend on how much info they actually provided*.

To see the info about a podcast, when listening to it, click on the main area of the display - as marked with a **large** red rectangle below:

[image]

This takes you to a sort of detailed view:

[image]

Clicking on the text description here takes you back to the first view (pictorial representation of the podcast).

One extra thing: Clicking on the little icon at top-right, that looks like a sort of list (shown in the **small** red rectangle in the first image above), takes you to the list of "episodes" that you have for this podcast, e.g.:

[image]

---

**Edit: What about viewing podcast info on iOS 5 iPad?**

This info subsequently moved to [@JasonSalaz's separate iPad question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30211/how-do-i-view-the-list-of-podcast-chapters-on-an-ipad-using-ios-5/30213#30213)

Comment: Which version of iOS are you using?

Comment: I'm using iOS 5 - NB the question is tagged with ios-5...

Comment: The music app on iOS 5 on an iPhone is very dramatically different than on an iPad. I don't believe I can do the same thing you've described here, which is very disappointing to me. I assumed (wrongly, I note) that all the changes the iPad version has, also made it to the iPhone. Talk about feeling left out in the cold.

Comment: @JasonSalaz I agree, but this question is about iPhone, not iPad - as you say, they are different beasts. Suggest you start a question about iPad instead (if one doesn't exist already) - and I'll add an iPad-based answer there...

Comment: You're one smart cookie :). http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/30211/1346

Comment: Doh - I've just gone ahead and edited my answer here - I'll move it to your new question!