# How do I view the list of podcast chapters on an iPad using iOS 5?

Tags: ipad, ios, podcasts

I subscribe to [Tiesto's Club Life Podcast](http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/tiesto-s-club-life-podcast/id251507798), and the episodes are released as very superbly crafted AAC files. Aside from containing audio data, they also:

- Define Podcast "Chapters" marked at the start/end of each song.
- Define custom artwork per chapter.
- Name chapters appropriately by attributing artist/title (and often remixer) of the particular track.

As of iOS 5, none of this appears to work. During playback art never changes, and there is no indication of the chapter information (making it hard to look up the song after the fact).

Has this information disappeared from being easily accessed? Or has it just been moved somewhere that isn't obvious for me to find?

Comment: Related: [Can I view the list of songs within a podcast while playing it?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/30097/1346), but note that it is for an iPhone and the answer appears to be completely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really doesn't seem to be a way to view this info at all on iOS 5 iPads, in Apple's "Music" app.

Further iPad iOS 5 podcast annoyances:

- If the main "Music" you listen to is podcasts, it's really annoying that you can no longer promote the "Podcasts" button from "More" to the main view: so you always have to go to "More" to see your podcasts.
- If you have a mixture of video and audio podcasts, you have to switch between the "Videos" and "Music" apps to see them.

For all these reasons, I gave up on the built-in iOS 5 podcast tools, and switched to [Podcaster](http://podcaster.fm/). It costs a small amount of money, but has so many convenience features built in that it's well worth it.

(It's actually iPhone only - but works fine on iPad, at 2x size, even for showing videos)

I particularly like:

- It downloads the latest episode of shows you subscribe to, but seamlessly shows you earlier ones too, so you can easily stream them
- Automatic downloading via WiFi - so no more need to connect my device to a PC to update lots of podcasts
- Back and forward buttons to go move 30 seconds back or forwards - or you can change the settings, and make these buttons go back/forward 10, then 20 then 30 seconds if clicked in quick succession.
- Small icon at top-right of screen shows/hide details of podcasts.
- Sleep facility (15, 30, 45, 60, 90 minutes)

(I'd like to include a link to the original question here where I saw Podcaster first mentioned, but there are so many answers singing its praises, I really don't remember which one I saw.)

**Edit**

And to answer your question about Tiesto's Club Life Podcast, yes, Podcaster displays that well. It shows the images as you listen, and at bottom-right of the screen there's a little chapters icon that shows name of each chapter, and its position (in minutes and seconds)

Furthermore, you can swipe upwards on the screen, when playing, to show the chapters.